# MySQL: START TRANSACTION sets 'autocommit' to off?

Tags: mysql

When I execute `START TRANSACTION` followed by `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'autocommit'` immediately, I see that the variable `autocommit` is still set to `ON`. Isn't this supposed to  set to `OFF` until I explicitly say `COMMIT`?

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that transactions just ignore the autocommit setting. So starting a transaction won't change the value of the autocommit variable. This makes sense as you would not want one user a's transaction to disable user b's autocommit while user a's transaction is processing.

This is not obvious by reading the document unless you read "autocommit mode" and "autocommit variable" as being two different things, which they are.

Comment: In the link I provided, it explicitly says that "autocommit mode" is disabled with `START TRANSACTION` without mentioning the "autocommit variable," but it  goes on to say that `"disabling autocommit mode by setting the autocommit variable to zero"`, which implies to me they are the same.. Am I not reading this correctly?

Comment: At that point in the document it is talking about how to shut autocommit mode off for the entire session and not talking about transactions. It's a badly written document, and that couple of paragraphs is a digression from talking about transactions and instead is giving more detail on what the autocommit variable is.

Comment: Although I can't find an article that discusses specifically about those two things, it seems like you're right based on other things I'm reading on the Internet. Thanks!